# Fit a parametric function to a ListPlot

Tags: fitting

Imagine I have a list of points that corresponds to points randomly placed on the circumference of a unit circle. I want code that fits a parametric curve corresponding to this list of points. Note that this code has to be robust. It should work for a unit square as well as a circle or an ellipse or any other closed curve. Which is the best in-built function to use for this?

Answer (score 1):

Without rolling your own, the simplest I can imagine is e.g. to use:

```
BoundaryMeshRegion[ConvexHullMesh[dat], PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

Of course, the resolution would depend on how many points you initially have.

For an ellipse you would e.g. have:

```
n = 20;
dat = {2 Sin[#], Cos[#]} & /@ RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n];
dat = RotationMatrix[Pi/4] . # & /@ dat; BoundaryMeshRegion[
 ConvexHullMesh[dat], PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

[image]

Or for a unit square:

```
dat = Table[(t1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]; t2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}]; 
   Which[t2 < 0.25, {-1, t1}, t2 < 0.5, {1, t1}, t2 < 0.75, {t1, -1}, 
    t2 <= 1, {t1, 1}]), n]
dat = RotationMatrix[Pi/4] . # & /@ dat; BoundaryMeshRegion[
 ConvexHullMesh[dat], PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

[image]